# Typescript: instance.constructor support?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, typescript

Is there any reason why Typescript 9.5 doesn't support the constructor property on instances:

```
class A{}
var a = new A();

a.constructor // gives error TS2094
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like this, you can always add this anywhere in your program:

```
interface Object {
    constructor: any;
}
```

Note that the property will not appear in Intellisense (because it comes from `Object`).

There's nothing stopping you from overwriting the 'constructor' property, so it's technically not safe to use as a way of doing things where you don't know anything about the object itself:

```
class Foo {
    'constructor'() {
        alert('hello');
    }
}

var x = new Foo();
x.constructor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you don't need to access it, so it looks like the view has been taken that it would create a lot of "auto-complete-noise" most of the time without need. TypeScript also handles the constructors for you when you use inheritance, so you don't even need access to it to perform this operation.

You can still get it if you like, with a type assertion.

```
var ctor = (<any>a).constructor;
```

Comment: There are times when access to the constructor property is needed: for accessing the final class from a method in a base class for example...  it is ok to remove it from auto completion etc... but why give an error...

Comment: another way of avoiding the error is to use the a['constructor'] syntax